# Django/Python TemplateDoesNotExist at / base.html

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am currently trying to learn Python and was watching some tutorials on youtube. I had thought of learning how to deploy dashboards to django and came across this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvU4zwO3Ao&t=720s&ab_channel=PipInstallPython). I was able to follow on the tutorial but when I try to run my code, I am receiving an error
[image]

I did what was in the tutorial and this is my file and codes

[image]

**Home App URLS.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

**Home App VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
   
def home(requests):
    return render(requests, 'home/welcome.html')
```

**Setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
]

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'slsuhris/static'),
]
```

**Project URLS.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
]
```

I have followed tutorial except for the migration using PostgreSQL thinking that it isn't necessary for building a dashboard. Why can't I access the files? Thank you.

I am using Python Community Edition. Does having error on the <!doctype html> got to do with this error?

[image]

Comment: The only base.html I can see is outside an app in the templates/partials folder. You need to add that path to TEMPLATES in settings.py

Comment: Maybe its enough to add partials/base.html. I am not sure if templates/ in the base directory of your project is part of the templates path by default.

Comment: Hi. That was the exact method that he used during the tutorial. He just created a directory with the same name as the one outside the app. Then he called it in the app html file using {% extends 'base.html' % }

Comment: Check the tutorial ... I am sure the base.html is not in partials but in templates directly

Comment: And yes, the error is community edition topic because you have django template tags before the DOCTYPE and pycharm community edition does not "know" that sequence. Just ignore it.

Comment: Hi! The base.html is under the templates and not the partial. The partials contain parts of the supports dashboard.

Comment: Ah okay. So the error is not major and won't affect my code?

Comment: No wont affect your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my mistake ... you are right, your base.html is in templates and this is what you need in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = 

....
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
....
```